# How do I fix the Authentication error?

Tags: 16.04

Well, after my successful installation of ubuntu 16.04 it hasn't been that great.

I ran terminal and did updates, etc. After that I decided to download the software center and after running it, I tried to download an app. An error popped up restricting me to download anything, or update the system the error said:

```
Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.78'}): org.debian.apt.change-repository
```

please help!

Comment: Run this command in terminal: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
`